# NFT Token Name and Symbol Naming Convention

Tags: nft

Should an organization use the same name and symbol for all NFT tokens it creates? (irrespective of which contract was used to mint the token). Are there advantages / disadvantages to this approach?

Any suggestions or guidance regarding name and symbol best practice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to naming **NFT** tokens and using symbols in different contracts depends on the use-case, both methods of using the same **Name** and **Symbol** or differents has their pros and cons :

If you're using the same name and symbol accross all **NFT's** can make the brand more recognisable, meaning a better brand identity, owners familiar with a set of NFT's will more readily recognize another set and the **User-Experience** overall is simplified.

The main problem will be the lack of **specificity**, meaning people could be confused if the tokens serves different purposes, with **differents attributes** or belong elsewhere.

By using different names, each collections would have its own specificity, meaning you customers can have big set of choice. the cons would be harder for newcomers to identify the brand and can be more complex when users manage the assets.

A viable strategy could be to manipulate **metadata** and create related names, offering a mix of uniform and diverse.

**Best regards, X**

Answer (score 0):

You can code a generic contract with multiple type of minting.
You can ask user to add attributes on his taste and mint.